# JQuery AutoGrow plugin non effective after AJAX function

Tags: jquery, textarea, autogrow

The jQuery autogrow plugin expands textarea to fit their content. The function is as follows.

```
(function($) {
    /*
     * Auto-growing textareas; technique ripped from Facebook
     */
    $.fn.autogrow = function(options) {

        this.filter('textarea').each(function() {

            var $this       = $(this),
                minHeight   = $this.height(),
                lineHeight  = $this.css('lineHeight');

            var shadow = $('<div></div>').css({
                position:   'absolute',
                top:        -10000,
                left:       -10000,
                width:      $(this).width(),
                fontSize:   $this.css('fontSize'),
                fontFamily: $this.css('fontFamily'),
                lineHeight: $this.css('lineHeight'),
                resize:     'none'
            }).appendTo(document.body);

            var update = function() {

                var val = this.value.replace(/</g, '&lt;')
                                    .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
                                    .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
                                    .replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');

                shadow.html(val);
                $(this).css('height', Math.max(shadow.height() + 20, minHeight));
            }

            $(this).change(update).keyup(update).keydown(update);

            update.apply(this);

        });

        return this;

    }

})(jQuery);
```

It is then triggered `$('textarea').autogrow();`. After a JQuery load function we load in a new textarea. Thus I triggered this.

```
$('.commentslogic').load(window.location.href + ' .commentslogic .inner', function(){
$('textarea').autogrow();
});
```

But it does not apply to the new textarea, furthermore there is no error reported in FireBug. Help!

Fiddle dee dee Fiddle dee dum http://jsfiddle.net/JTmND/8/

Comment: It would help immensely to post a jsFiddle of this code.

Comment: If I am not mistaken js fiddle does not provide support for an AJAX call. If I am wrong, please state

Comment: @JoshSmith simulating fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JTmND/8/

Comment: Glad you figured it out. For future reference jsFiddle does provide an interface for testing AJAX requests in the left sidebar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As figured out in the comments, this fiddle is the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/JTmND/11/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('textarea').autogrow();

    $('.button').click(function() {
        $('.test').html('<textarea></textarea>');
        $('.test').find('textarea').autogrow();
    });
});
```

It doesn't matter how the new textareas are added to the dom (manually or by ajax callback method), it is necessary to use jquery selectors to assign the autogrow functionality.

Comment: And `$('textarea').triggerHandler('change');` ?

Comment: Your fiddle does not simulate the problem. Here is mine that does. http://jsfiddle.net/JTmND/8/